# Docker Image Size a Concern - Best Practice to create a base python image with ubuntu

Tags: python, image, ubuntu, docker

**Need**: I want to create a minimal size python docker image on top of ubuntu14.04.

**Problem**: Ubuntu docker 14.04 image has 188MB size. On creating image with below Dockerfile, the image size becomes 486MB. Which is too much for such a small addition. I understand the less the number of instruction the lesser will be the size of the image. So I have kept it minimal.

What am I doing wrong?? and what is the best way to create a light dockerimage for python.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q curl \
build-essential \
python-dev \
python-pip \
vim \
wget && \
apt-get autoremove -y && \
apt-get clean && \
apt-get autoclean && \
echo -n > /var/lib/apt/extended_states && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
rm -rf /usr/share/man/?? && \
rm -rf /usr/share/man/??_*
```

Comment: Use Alpine Linux instead of Ubuntu; don't install vim curl and wget on the container.

Comment: @rob is alpine made from ubuntu14.04? want to use the same thing we use in prod... does vim curl and wget occupying like 300MB??

Comment: It's a different Linux distribution but it is specifically designed to be light weight. Shoot over to https://alpinelinux.org/ to find out more. Talk to your ops people they should be impressed with the result.

Comment: @RobKielty What about people who want to move their current infra to docker? They been using ubuntu for years. Moving to completely new linux distro aint a solution for everyone. What do you say?

Comment: @RobKielty And removing curl wget and vim did not bring significant reduction in size. It is still 378MB :(

Comment: Linux is Linux. They will just have to learn a new package management app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect answer here.

Using Ubuntu as a base image is a fine place to start, especially for legacy applications which expect to be deployed into an environment that needs to emulate a virtual machine. I would advise not letting this drive all your decision making, because containers are not virtual machines. They all share the kernel of the host machine. As @RobKielty states "Linux is Linux".

Fact is if your application has very few dependencies (for example go programs) then the extra size of the base image is simply redundancy. The use of alternative base images like Alpine is driven by a desire for faster downloads, but it also has security benefits too. It eliminates unused packages that would otherwise need to be patched. However... it's not a free lunch because using Alpine means more effort installing dependencies (that would already exist in a larger image like Ubuntu)

In conclusion I would refer you to the community python image. If you look carefully there are several available image tags, using python built on top of a variety of base images. Might save you a lot of effort.

https://hub.docker.com/_/python/

Hope this helps.